# this.Touch - Event firing multiple times, don't know how to unsubscribe

Tags: android, events, xamarin.android, unsubscribe

This problem should be fairly simple (I think), but I don't know how to do it correctly. I am still very new to programming.

I have a simple class that inherits from EditText. There are 2 problems:

1. Initially, the Touch event fires 3 times, the second touch will fire the event 5 times and so on. What is going on here?
2. I don't know how to unsubscribe the event, or a at what stage. Normally, when working with an activity, I simply subscribe during OnResume and unsubscribe during OnPause. What is the right solution in this case? Should I write a custom method and call that from a parent class? Should I implement IDisposable or something similar? Should I write the class in a different way?

This is my custom edit text demo class:

```
    namespace HelloWorld_Android {
        class DemoEditText : EditText {
            public DemoEditText (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs) {
                this.Touch += HandleTouch;
            }

            void HandleTouch (object sender, TouchEventArgs e) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Fired");
            }
        }
    }
```

The activity:

```
    namespace HelloWorld_Android {
        [Activity (Label = "HelloWorld_Android", MainLauncher = true)]
        public class MainActivity : Activity {
            protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle) {
                base.OnCreate (bundle);
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            }
        }
    }
```

My XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <HelloWorld_Android.DemoEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/test"
         />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is fixed, however no code has been changed. I think this was due to some kind of bug within xamarin.android 4.12, as of now I am using Xamarin.Android 4.12.6. I had other (unrelated) problems with WebConnectionStream.WriteRequestAsync (fixed in 4.12.6) as well, maybe something else went wrong which caused a memory leak (not removing touch delegate) or something, not sure.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/touch/part_3_touch_in_android/), `View.Touch` is is for touch *events*.

I would interrogate the `TouchEventArgs` that your handler is called with to see what specific gesture it is receiving. At a minimum I would expect it to receive two calls - one each for the start and end of the touch gesture.

Comment: So, I wasn't working on this project for some time and installed several xamarin.android updates in between. Today, I fired up the project once again, no code has been changed, and the touch event is only triggered twice as it should (like you mentioned), and not firing more and more times on every new touch. I'm not sure, but I think that this problem was due to a bug with touch events in xamarin.android which has been fixed.